# Can I call SMO from pure T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, scripting, sql-clr, ole-automation

I know how to script a stored procedure using PowerShell and SMO:

```
[System.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")  | out-null
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" 
$srv.databases['MyDatabase'].StoredProcedures['MyProc'].TextBody
```

But since I want to use the procedure text within a query, I wonder whether I can call SMO in some way within pure T-SQL.

Must only run in development environment.

BTW: A function returning the definition of a stored procedure with a given name would solve my current problem but not answer my question.

*Edit:*

I want to find which procedures reference a given table when I use this query:

```
SELECT p.name --, definition 
FROM sys.sql_modules m
join sys.objects p on m.object_id = p.object_id
where p.type = 'P'
and definition like '%SearchForThis%'
```

That is exactly the same information I want to get using SMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd use the [sp_OA% stored procs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190501.aspx) for this. Or [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) since SQL Server 2005.

It can't be done via T-SQL directly because T-SQL is for data manipulation. So you have to use one of the 2 methods above. Unless you want to use xp_cmdshell to run a powershell script.

This also brings up one limitation of T-SQL: how to get an object definition to disk? And I guess one reason why you asked this. Again, CLR or sp_OA% will do it.

One thing to note is that almost *every* method and property in SMO maps to a SQL command or query. So using T-SQL to call SMO which is effectively T-SQL is circular.

And to get the stored procedure definition you'd use [OBJECT_DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx)... to get the other properties available in SMO you'd use OBJECT_PROPERTY or query the system objects.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? The SMO assemblies don't seem to be available from inside (from stored CLR procedures). Can I add them in some way? Is it a safe thing to do?

Comment: @GSerg: what are you trying to do? You don't need to use SQL to call CLR to call SMO? Everything available via SMO is already in raw T-SQL

Comment: Alas, it's not. I've got a CLR stored procedure, from inside of which I must figure the default value of the given parameter of the given SQL stored procedure. This information is not available via SQL, because `sys.parameters` only contains default values for CLR objects; for SQL objects [documentation suggests parsing the result of `OBJECT_DEFINITION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx). On contrary, SMO returns the default value of an SQL object's parameter just fine.

Comment: @GSerg: ah yes, remember now, been answered before on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bdefault+%2B%22sys.parameters%22 You have no way to do it in SQL which is odd. Maybe SMO isn't installed on your box where you are develoeping the CLR? Just a guess...

Comment: It is installed on my dev box, I can reference the assembly from a "normal" project and it works fine. But for "SQL Server" projects (the ones you have for creating stored procedures), the SMO assembly is not on the list of allowed references (which are few). So I wondered if it was possible to copy SMO assemblies to SQL Server and whether it was a sensible thing to do.

Comment: @GSerg: might be worth asking a new question on Stack Overflow. More client programmers there who could help you further.

Comment: Well. I've finally tricked my SQL Server project into allowing me to reference SMO. And what do I get when I execute my CLR function on the server: `System.Exception: This functionality is disabled in the SQLCLR. It is recommended that you execute from your client application. (at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager..ctor(SqlConnection sqlConnectionObject))`. Apparently your advice to employ CLR for this particular purpose is not valid after all :(

Comment: @GSerg: have you asked on SO? Someone may know a workaround

Comment: Hey there. @GSerg is correct: the SMO library is specifically blocked if it detects that it is being called from within SQL Server's CLR host. I answered a duplicate of this question on S.O. last year with the same findings: [Invoking SMO via T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675060/invoking-smo-via-t-sql/29050059#29050059). There is no work around that will allow SMO to work in SQLCLR.

Answer (score 0):

As it relates to the question as stated (and not the desire as stated in the "*Edit*"):

NO, it is not possible to call SMO from T-SQL. It cannot be done via the OLE Automation stored procedures (i.e. `sp_OA*`), nor via SQLCLR.

### OLE Automation

I'm not sure what the *OLEComponent* name would be, but you can create objects by specifying their *clsid*. Of course, finding that for SMO isn't easy either, but I did find two references out in the inter-webz:

1. [what is the CLSID and PROG ID of Microsoft.sqlserver.Management.Smo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1707952/577765) (on Stack Overflow)
2. [To create.NET object from simple JScript.](http://www.progtown.com/post2774919.html#p2774919) (on Programmer's Town)

```sql
DECLARE @ObjectToken INT, @HResult INT;
DECLARE @Source VARCHAR(500), @Description VARCHAR(500);

EXEC @HResult = sp_OACreate '{603F0A84-5631-3CA0-BCE0-C96597C2C1A0}', @ObjectToken OUT;
--EXEC @HResult = sp_OACreate '{755F7A20-E39C-31E0-8174-2E430C2C4E7A}', @ObjectToken OUT;

IF (@HResult <> 0)
BEGIN
   EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @ObjectToken, @Source OUT, @Description OUT;
   RAISERROR('OLE Automation error. HResult: %x; @Source: %s; @Description: %s',
             16, 1, @HResult, @Source, @Description);
   RETURN;
END;

EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken;
```

Both values return:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   OLE Automation error. HResult: 80040154; @Source: ODSOLE Extended Procedure; @Description:  Class not registered

Even though SMO is COM-visible, I suspect that it not working here is related to the following requirement, which is stated in the MSDN page for [sp_OACreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189763.aspx)

> The specified OLE object must be valid and must support the **IDispatch** interface.

The SMO library does not appear to implement the `IDispatch` interface.

Even if someone does manage to find a way to get this to work, it is still ill-advised considering that the OLE Automation stored procedures have been deprecated since the release of SQL Server 2005.

### SQLCLR

While SQLCLR would seem like the natural way to go with SMO (since SMO is also .NET), this definitely does not work as the SMO library specifically detects if it is being used within SQL Server, and if so, aborts with the following error message:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "SmoTest":
>   System.Exception: **This functionality is disabled in the SQLCLR. It is recommended that you execute from your client application.**
>   System.Exception:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager..ctor()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server..ctor()

There is no way around this (well, unless you are Microsoft ;).